# ArcGIS and dynamic legends

Tags: jquery, arcgis

I have this simple function javascript function that dynamically generates an arcgis map based on parameters passed. The function works well except that it doesn't refresh the legend.

I tried to clear the legendDiv, append it, prepend it using jQuery before this function loads but it only loads blank but as the code is right now, the old legend still remains despite the map hence response changing.

```
function generate_map(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, wkid, graphic)
{

$j("#mapDiv").empty(); 
var map,
webmapId = graphic;

require([
  "esri/map",
"esri/arcgis/utils",
"esri/dijit/Legend",
"esri/dijit/HomeButton",
"esri/dijit/Print",
"esri/tasks/geometry",
 "dojo/domReady!"], function (Map, arcgisUtils, Legend, HomeButton) {
    arcgisUtils.createMap(webmapId, "mapDiv", {
    mapOptions: {
    extent : new esri.geometry.Extent({
    "xmin": xmin,
    "ymin": ymin,
    "xmax": xmax,
    "ymax": ymax,
    "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": wkid
    }
    })
    }} ).then(function (response) {
    map = response.map     

    var legend = new Legend({
        map: map,
        layerInfos:(arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response))
    }, "legendDiv");
    legend.refresh();

    var home = new HomeButton({
        map: map
          }, "HomeButton");
          home.startup();
    });

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `autoUpdate:true` property to your legend object.